# Installation Meteorite on mac os x 10.8.2

Tags: meteor

I am trying to install meteorite

```
MacBook-Air-Voldemar:packages voldemar$ sudo npm install -g meteorite
Password:
```

and I am getting error

```
sudo: npm: command not found
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: yes like prashant said, or you can get http://nodejs.org/ installed and use npm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node already has a node js package for OS X.

Goto http://nodejs.org and press install to download the nodejs package, when installed npm should be installed with it.

Comment: thanks, I installed node, but I am trying for example "mrt install fullcalendar", it returns "Done installing smart packages", but when I am trying to add package to existing project "meteor add fullcalendar" it returns fullcalendar: "no such package"

Comment: fullcalendar is a meteorite only package you can only install and use it with `mrt`

Comment: I do "mrt add fullcalendar", Meteorite successfully install package. Then watch list of meteor packages "meteor list | grep fullcalendar" and there is no new package.

Comment: meteor can't see the packages at all, if you do `mrt list` it should show

Answer (score 2):

The message says that you have not installed the node package manager `npm`.

Before installing npm, make sure you have noted down the path to node. It is most probably in `/usr/local/lib/node`.

Then do,

```
git clone http://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
sudo make install
```

Now add the path to node, by adding the following in `.bashrc`

```
export NODE_PATH = "/path/to/node"
```

You will also need the `npm` executable, so add the path to npm bin,

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"
```

Then save and exit `.bashrc` and do

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This evaluates the edits and the changes reflect in the shell. Now you can go ahead with `sudo npm install -g meteorite`